# Publish an App in Sandbox/Production

Tags: sandbox, connected-apps

I have created a connected app to allow REST API calls from a form system I use.  This has been working OK in developer but I am struggling to get a Sandbox working in the same manner.  I know it says something about using "Developer" to create apps...does that mean I simply create the app in developer and use a change set to push it to Sandbox and then production?

Simply put I can log in via REST but I always receive BAD Requests (400) when trying to Query or Insert?  If I use the same code via hurl.it it works as expected.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Is the Developer org separate from the Sandbox and Production, e.g. a separate SFDC free Dev Org as that would require deployment by another tool not Change Sets? It will require a Test class and over 75% coverage of the code to allow deployment via any method.  With the App it would be helpful to add the code to your question to allow informed comment to be made.

Comment: Firstly yes it is seperate - thanks.  Secondly there is no code in Salesforce, I simply create the Connected App and use the client id/secret for my forms.  In the Developer edition testing the only difference in the rest API is the URL (login.salesforce.com instead of test.salesforce.com).  As it works via hurl.it I don't think it's the form system and the fact it works on the developer but as soon as I change to the sandbox settings (the settings are username/password/clientid/clientsecret/url and api version btw) it doesn't let me do anything in the org - only login.